# Extract common entry between 2 tables in excel

Tags: excel

I have two tables like below, I need to extract common entry between the 2 tables and put this in a 3rd table.

```
 Table 1     Table2      Table 3
   A           A           A
   B           X           B
   C           B           C
   D           Z
   E           C
```

Is there a way to do this in Excel?

Comment: You can use VLOOKUP. If it returns NA then it's not part of the second table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2,$C$2:$C$6,0)),A2,"")
```

copy down.

[image]